# Start a QT Thread when button is clicked

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

This is a sample code with just a push button and a textedit, i need to write line x line using a loop in a textedit when button is clicked.

The problem is that i need to implement threads because without them the program crashes or it doesn't write line x line, but all together when the loop ends;
and i need to implement in my application a textedit that shows info while the program loads "something".

So my question is, how to rewrite this code using threads to write in textedit when button is clicked?
The method i should run when the button is clicked is "write"
it should work like a print inside a for loop , it would print not all at once

```
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



  class Ui_MainWindow(object):

   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 220, 321, 71))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 100, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


  def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.write)

  def write(self):
    string=""
    for i in range(1000):
        string="\n"+str(i)
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText(string)

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>First of all it is recommended not to modify the class generated by Qt Designer so you must regenerate the file and assume that it is called mainwindow.py: `pyuic5 your_file.ui -o mainwindow.py -x`</sub>.

Considering the above, the logic is to generate the information in another thread and send it to the GUI to modify it:

**main.py**

```py
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow


class WriterWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self):
        string = ""
        for i in range(1000):
            string = "\n"+str(i)
            self.textChanged.emit(string)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.writer_worker = WriterWorker()
        self.writer_worker.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.writer_worker.start)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_text_changed(self, text):
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you explain better what you did? what is this  @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str) and how signals works?

Comment: Thank you, i got this error messagge: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainwindow' .. if i do pip install mainwindow, it doesn't exists

Comment: @giuliaresto Have you read the first part of my answer which is in small letters? If you do you will see that you will no longer have that problem.

Comment: Yes sorry, i did and now i get this : TypeError: QMainWindow(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: Thank you but now : "string" is not defined, i'm sorry for all these questions but i will understand the code, now not yet

Comment: Now it works, thank you, but it write in textedit when i execute not on buttonclick

Comment: @giuliaresto try again :-) opssss

Comment: Now it finally works! i really apprecciate your help!

Comment: it's not that you know also how to automatic switch view on new generated lines? if not don't worry

Comment: @giuliaresto That is already asked and resolved in SO so I will avoid answering so that you try to do the search first.